# How to make Laravel's Validator $rules optional?

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Let's say I have `User` model with two methods:

**User.php**

```
class User extends Eloquent
{  
    /* Validation rules */
    private static $rules = array(
        'user'  => 'unique:users|required|alpha_num',
        'email' => 'required|email'
    );

    /* Validate against registration form */
    public static function register($data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            /*... do someting */
        }
        else
        {
            /* .. do something else */
        }
    }

    /* Validate against update form */
    public static function update($data)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
        if($validator->fails())
        {
            /*... do someting */
        }
        else
        {
            /* .. do something else */
        }
    }
}
```

**My question**: How can I make validation rules optional, so even if data for `update()` would be just `email` field, it would ignore `user` and still validate to `true`.
Is this even possible or am I missing something?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure if I'm getting your question right but if the user is optional you should remove 'required' from the validator. This way you will have:

```
'user'  => 'unique:users|alpha_num',
```

instead of:

```
'user'  => 'unique:users|required|alpha_num',
```

On the other hand I create a custom method for my models that is able to return custom validation rules depending on incoming parameters.

For example:

```
private function getValidationRules($rules)
{
    if ($rules == UPDATE_EMAIL)
    {
        return array('email' => 'required|email');
    } else {
        return array(
            'user'  => 'unique:users|required|alpha_num',
            'email' => 'required|email'
        );
    }
}
```

I guess it's only a personal choice, but I have found that getting the validation rules from a method allows more control over what I really want to validate, especially when you want to perform some advanced validations.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think the question is how to skip unique on update.

Comment: @Joeri he is not saying anything about skiping unique on update, he says that sometimes he'd like to validate the username, and sometimes he'd like to validate the email. Couple of situations for this type of validation come to my mind, for example a form that allows certain fields to be null depending on the status of another field.

Comment: Carlos. True. But my experience is that with the unique laravel will not update. I think because the column it's no longer unique?

Comment: Well, that depends on the constraints at a database level, rules on a model can't override database constraints. But, it is posible to specify unique on a model but not at the table, and still allow duplicates by changing the rules of the model depending on special circumstances.

Comment: Are you suggesting there is a use case for a table not requiring unique usernames that you want to check for uniqueness in the model?

Comment: Not at all, but under specific circumstances you may want to allow for example a duplicate email.

Answer (score 2):

In stock Laravel, you can call `update()` on a model, and it won't validate by default, which will give you the desired behavior you described. In the code you posted, you're explicitly overriding the `update()` method to force validation.

There are two ways to make the "user" field optional in the code you posted:

1. Don't set "required" in your $rules for that field.

   ```
   'user'  => 'unique:users|alpha_num',
   ```
2. Don't override the `update()` method to force validation before updating.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
private static $rules = array(
    'user'  => 'unique:users|required|alpha_num',
    'email' => 'required|email'
);
private static $update_rules = array(
    'user'  => 'required|alpha_num',
    'email' => 'required|email'
);

* Validate against registration form */
public static function register($data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, static::$rules);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        /*... do someting */
    }
    else
    {
        /* .. do something else */
    }
}

/* Validate against update form */
public static function update($data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, static::$update_rules);
    if($validator->fails())
    {
        /*... do someting */
    }
    else
    {
        /* .. do something else */
    }
}
```