# Laravel validation service with unique fields

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4

I'm using a validation service to validate user submitted form input (something along the lines of: http://laravel.io/bin/vrk).

Using this approach (validation service classes) to validate user submitted form data against a set of rules, how can I validate user submitted data when rules have a `unique` rule. For example, if a user has the username of `John` then when I try to update the model validation fails (because `John` exists as a username, even though it belongs to the current model).

To solve this in Laravel I can do something like `'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,username'.$id`. How should I modify my current code, in the link, to best accommodate this? Should I have separate validator classes depending on the scenario (for example, UserCreateValidator, UserUpdateValidator, etc). Or should I do something like create separate validation rules in `UserValidator` class and pass which rule I want as an argument to either the constructor or the `passes()` method when calling UserValidator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do something like this

First update `UserValidator` rules like this.

```
class UserValidator extends Validator {

    // Override parent class $rules
    protected $rules = [
        'default' => [
            'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|between:6,16|confirmed',
            'password_confirmation' => 'required|between:6,16'
        ],
        'update' => [
            'username' => null,
        ]
    ];
}
```

Then modify `Validator`'s `passes` method like this

```
public function passes($rule = null) {

    $rules = $this->rules['default'];
    if ($rule && isset($this->rules[$rule])) {
        $rules = array_merge($rules, $this->rules[$rule]);
    }

    $validator = \Validator::make($input, $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $this->validator = $validator;
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Then in your controller's `PUT` method, this will merge `update` rules to `default` rules

```
$rule = 'update';

// user has changed his username
if ($input['username'] !== $old_username) {
    $rule = 'create'; // validate uniqueness
}

else {
    unset($input['username']); // remove it, we don't validate it anymore since it's the same
}

$validator->passes($rule); // override 'default' rules with 'update' rules
```

You don't have to change your controller's `POST` method, it'll stay the same

```
$validator->passes(); // use 'default' rules
```

Comment: If I was to change the `username` rule to `required|alpha_dash` wouldn't that mean that a username could be passed in that matches another username in the table and it would still validate?

Comment: Yes, the logic for updating username is like this, If the new username is not equal old username then we'll have to validate uniqueness, if it's the same just ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what are you doing on post?

Because this is what you should be doing:

```
$user = User::find($userId);

$user->username = $input['username'];
$user->email = $input['email'];

$user->save();
```

To update a record.

Or

```
$input = array('username' => 'w0rldart', 'email' => 'hahafu@dumbledore.com');
// Retrieve the user by the attributes, or create it if it doesn't exist, 
// based on the data above, which can come from an Input::all();
$user = User::firstOrCreate($input);
```

... many possibilities. But you could also do:

```
$input = array_forget($input, 'username');
```

To comply with your case, by removing the `username` index from the input array.

This is all I call tell you, based on the information you gave us. If you want more, post the controller's put method.

### Update:

Here's my version of your PUT method: http://laravel.io/bin/OaX

I really think that `try catch` syntax is useless, since it's obvious that a `User` model will always be there. But I still don't know what you're trying to update. Even though I can't test it right now, I don't think that updating should be giving that problem, and if it does, retrieve user by username/id then unset the `username` index in your input array, and update it according to your specifications.

Comment: To elaborate, the controller looks something like this http://laravel.io/bin/WbD. I want to validate the form submission with the validator service and only call save if validation passes. This works for creating but fails when creating because of the unique constraint on the username field.

Comment: Fails when updating, you wanted to say, right? Just as I mentioned in my comment, what are you trying to update? The username?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding right, you have issues updateng data because of primary key constraints on your model. What you need to do is to create 2 sets of rules, one for insert, and one for update.

Asuming you have a set of rules like this:

```
protected $rules = [
'id' => 'required|unique:users'
]
```

You should implement something like this:

```
protected $rules = [
'id' => 'required|unique|unique:users,id,' . $this->id
];
```

This should tell laravel to ignore the duplicate id in the table users for the specified id, in this case, the id for the current object.

You can read more about this on laravel's documentation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation

> **unique:table,column,except,idColumn**
>
> The field under validation must be unique on a given database table.
>   If the column option is not specified, the field name will be used.

Comment: Thanks, but what I meant specifically was should I store these two sets of rules in the one class, for example UserValidator, or have separate specific validators like UserUpdateValidator, UserCreatorValidator, etc? I'll elaborate in the question, apologies

Comment: When you use a validator you must tell it wich set of rules it should use. You may refer to this other question for further illustration: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18447404/how-to-make-laravels-validator-rules-optional/

Answer (score 0):

A little modification in `UserValidator` class

```
class UserValidator extends Validator {

    // Override parent class $rules
    protected $rules = [
        'username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|between:6,16|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|between:6,16'
    ];

    // ADD THIS
    public function __construct(Array $rules = array())
    {
        parent::__construct();
        if(count($rules)){
            foreach($rules as $k => $v) $this->rules[$k] = $v;
        }
    }
}
```

In your controller `putUpdate` method

```
$user = User::whereUsername($username)->firstOrFail();
$rules = ['username' => 'required|alpha_dash|unique:users,username,'. $user->id];
// Pass the rule to update the rule for username in this method
$validator = \Services\Validators\UserValidator(Input::all(), $rules);
```

Check [the manual here](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-unique).