# Laravel validator `required` fails for empty string also

Tags: php, macos, validation, laravel

I'm trying laravel `required` validator in my code, unfortunately it fails for even empty string. I do not want it fail for empty string.

```
$validator = \Validator::make(array("name"=>""), array("name"=>"required"));
if ($validator->fails()){
    var_dump($validator->messages());
} else {
    die("no errors :)");
}
```

It gives me the following output

```
object(Illuminate\Support\MessageBag)[602]
  protected 'messages' => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'The name field is required.' (length=27)
  protected 'format' => string ':message' (length=8)
```

It is supposed to pass, since i'm giving an empty string as the `name` field.

The above behavior happens in OSX environment (PHP Version 5.5.18), but it works fine in linux environment (PHP Version 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5).

Comment: The `required` rule actually returns false if you pass an empty string.

Comment: I remember answering a similar question where the person wanted validation only if the field was present in the form, you may want to check it out and possibly reuse the code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595528/laravel-only-validate-items-that-are-posted-and-ignore-rest-of-validation-array/23595964#23595964

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `required` rule actually returns false if you pass an empty string.

If we look at the code (`Illuminate\Validation\Validator`)

```
protected function validateRequired($attribute, $value)
{
    if (is_null($value))
    {
        return false;
    }
    elseif (is_string($value) && trim($value) === '')
    {
        return false;
    }

    // [...]

    return true;
}
```

I think your only option here is to write your [own validation rule](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#available-validation-rules) that checks if the value is not null:

```
Validator::extendImplicit('attribute_exists', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    return ! is_null($value);
});
```

(The `extendImplicit` is needed because with `extend` custom rules will only run when the value is not an empty string)

And then use it like this:

```
\Validator::make(array("name"=>""), array("name"=>"attribute_exists"));
```

Answer (score 14):

I use this:

```
'my_field' => 'present'
```

Comment: I believe this should now be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one. It does exactly what the the op is looking for.

Comment: `present|nullable|string` if you expect a string. `required` matches all the types.

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.6 you can use just this:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'my_field' => 'required|string|nullable'
    ];
}
```

Might work on older versions as well, I only tried on 5.6

Answer (score 0):

> i have developed my own way to process optional input. i use associative array for validation.

```
$rules = array('sltcategoryid' => 'required',   
            'txttitle' => 'required|min:10|max:255',    
            'txtdetail' => 'required|min:10|max:255',   
            'rdocontenttype' => 'required', 
            'rdoislive' => 'required');
         if($request->rdocontenttype=="1" || $request->rdocontenttype=="2" && trim($request->txtcontent)=="")
            $rules["txtcontent"]="required|min:10|max:2048";
         else if ($request->rdocontenttype=="3" && isset($request->fildata)==false)
             $rules["fildata"] ="required|mimes:png,jpg,jpeg,pdf,doc,xls,ppt,bmp,zip";
         $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),$rules);
         if ($validator->fails()) 
                return redirect('content/create')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
             else 
                return back()->with("message","content processed successfully");
```