# What is the best way to ensure that a field is always present with a non-empty value in a Laravel request

Tags: laravel

For this purpose, I end up doing:

```
    $request->validate([
        "name"    => "required|present|filled",
        "phone"   => "required|present|filled",
        "message" => "required|present|filled",
    ]);
```

...and it really looks like an overkill to me. I started doing it when I learnt that they  (`required`, `present`, and `filled`) all do very different things.

Is this actually an overkill or they are all actually required to ensure that a form field is always present in the request, and that it's value is never empty.

Comment: You can see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28020637/laravel-validator-required-fails-for-empty-string-also
 Write a customized validation rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple `required` is what you exactly need.

As docs said:

> The field under validation must be present in the input data and not
>   empty. A field is considered "empty" if one of the following
>   conditions are true:
>
> - The value is null.
> - The value is an empty string.
> - The value is an empty array or empty Countable object.
> - The value is an uploaded file with no path.

Answer (score 2):

Only

```
required
```

will done the job.